# Accessing Array of Inputs for Custom Angular Component

Tags: angular

I have a component in my Angular app named `access` that helps me decide, based on some input parameters, if a user should be able to access a certain tab on my UI.

For example:

```
<access type="type" name="name" feature="feature"></access>
```

You can imagine that some may only be restricted by one type of input parameter but others, like the one above, may need to have all inputs `ANDED (&&)` in order for the access to be allowed.

Is it possible to, on a case by case basis, in my component, to get all of the inputs that are currently set (if there are more than 1) and then `AND` them all together to get an access?

I am currently doing something like:

```
@Input()
public set accesses(value: string[]) { // loop through each and && }
```

The component would look something like:

```
@Input()
public set type(value: string) {
    this.hasAccess = this.myService.hasAccess(value);
}
```

Where the above is essentially repeated for each input (`type`, `name`, `feature`)

Possibly, for each element in my array, I can `&&` the result of each ones and end up with a `hasAccess` to use on the template:

*access component*

```
<span *ngIf="hasAccess">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</span>
```

Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: can you provide some code how the construct could potentialy look ?

Comment: @RichardFox, does the above help? I've added an example of what the component could look like